# how access folder specific app android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, directory

I have the following code with which to access a specific folder of the external storage, the question is how I can do the same but for a folder of my internal storage application

```
        val rootPath = "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary:"
            val samPath = Uri.parse("$rootPath${Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS}%2fajua")    
            val REQUEST_CODE_PICK_FILE = 1
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
            intent.type = "image/*"    //specify file type
            intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, samPath)    
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PICK_FILE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have the following code with which to access a specific folder of the external storage

Not reliably. Please do not assume that you can hand-assemble a `Uri` that will work.

> the question is how I can do the same but for a folder of my internal storage application

Sorry, but the Storage Access Framework UI has no access to your app's portion of [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).